# Blazor WebAssembly ignores breakpoints

Tags: c#, debugging, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I couldn't debug my Client-side Blazor, breakpoints would simple not get hit.

I also disabled the "use previews of .NET Core SDK" (Options->Environment->Preview Features), which I was using previously.

Visual Studio 16.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My .csproj had:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Simply removed the line with DebugType and it's working as intended.